# Creating new pages dynamically based on amount of database entries? (and sorting issue)

Tags: php, sql

I didn't quite know how to thoroughly explain my question in the title, but here's my idea:

My website takes user submissions and writes them to the database (they're displayed on a new page). They're ordered by time of submission (oldest first). I'd like to reverse the order they're displayed in (so it would display newest submissions at the top), and only display 20-30 per page, creating a new page every time it exceeded that number. I'm new to php, and completely unsure on what to do here. Thanks for any help.(:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The term for this is pagination, and as the others have said, it is something that has to be handled by your query (as the issue isn't just a matter of the UI, but also the number of records and their size returned from the database).

Answer (score 1):

Create an SQL Query, no need for PHP code.

Out the top of my head

```
SELECT * FROM submissions
ORDER BY subID ASC
LIMIT 30
```

Use mysql_query() and manipulate the LIMIT with PHP

e.g.

```
$limit = 25;

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM submissions ORDER BY subID ASC LIMIT $limit");
```

Comment: Well, it's sorted inherently. There's no date value involved, it just automatically sorts by order of submission.

Comment: Changed it to reflect an ID instead

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery.DataTables](http://datatables.net/) will do all this for you.

Comment: Checking it out, I'll see what it can do.